# assign one line to the other line in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel document, then I use `read_excel()` function, and change the Excel document to a DataFrame called `df`

Then I want to process every line in `df`, if the line fits, then I will insert/append this line to a new variable called `df1`

How do I solve it?

I think I can assign one line in `df` to one line in `df1`, so in every loop:

`df1.loc[0] = df.loc[0]`

But there is a question is that I find if I `print df1`, and the data in `df1` is `NaN`.

What if I use append?

`df1 = df1.append(df.loc[0])`

There is an exception: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

What should I do?

How to transport one line to the other line?

**|n1|n2|n3

0   | A |  B  | C

1   | E |  F  | G

this is `df`, for example. and I want to select the index which is 0, and I want to assign it to a new dataframe variable called `df1`

so this is `df1` in my mind:

**|n1|n2|n3

0   | A |  B  | C

but if I use `df1.loc[0] = df.loc[0]`, then `df1` will be:

**|n1|n2|n3

0   | nan |  nan  | nan

Comment: What do you mean by "if the line fits"?

Comment: Please provide some data and the expected output. Right now it is hard to tell what you are after...

Comment: meet the requirement, I mean

Comment: Iterating through a df like this is counter-intuitive in pandas. If you provide some sample data for `df` and the desired `df1` then we can probably help. You need to be specific on the requirement.

Comment: n1 n2 n3 is the columns, and ABCEFG is the data

Comment: again please have a read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). and I also think you at least learn how to use the text editor of SO as well; for everyone's benefits your codes, sample data should be formatted correctly, and it's easy to do as well. please do that next time, thanks.

Comment: OK, I will do it!

Answer (score 0):

I am Chinese, I should use Unicode.

So the columns' name should be:

`u'你好'`

`u'谢谢'`